# Largest area in matrix

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search-tree

I've been aksed to write a program that finds the largest area of equal neighbour elements in a rectangular matrix and prints its size. I tried to construct a 2d array with some numbers but I think that I should switch to using a tree or something in order to solve this problem. Chould somebody suggest a possible way of solving it? 
For example: [image]
"Hint: use the algorithm Depth-first search or Breadth-first search."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a standard maze search problem.  I suggest you use recursion to find all the elements which you haven't been to before which have the same number as the one you have found.  You can either update the matrix as you go or create a copy to keep track of the cells you have visited. So you don't need a tree or even an additional complex data structure.

> use the algorithm Depth-first search or Breadth-first search

These are two types of recursive searches. I suspect you could implement both of these to see how they behave.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I do appreciate it! :)

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev you can try two loops for/for for all possible starting points.  Starting at that point and with that number, using recursion you can find all the cells around it for the same number, set the cell to invalid e.g. `-1` to make sure you doing go other the same cell twice.